# How to add data in object with index in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming, data-analysis

first at all: I am completly new to R. So please excuse me if the question is a little crude.

I am trying multivariate clustering of functional data. Therefore I used Ramsay & Silvermans [fda](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fda/index.html)-Package to build basis spline expansion systems, fill them with curves and applyed the [funclust](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiSla727bvPAhVH2CwKHV7jCfgQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FFunclustering%2FFunclustering.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGkbt7acrNhv4GXL5oqrYX-oeJiiw) to the dataset.

The funclust-Function gives a proposal as vector for the clustering named as clsResult e.g.

```
clsResult <- c(2,2,2,3,3,2,3,2,2)
```

At the next step I would like to calculate statistical measures like mean, standard deviation,... That is why I wish to separate the data for each class and calculate the statistics.

An example for the mean calculation:

```
uniGroups <- sort(unique(as.vector(clsResult)))
j = 1
for (i in uniGroups) {
  obsItems <- which(cls %in% i)
  fdClsMean[j] <- mean.fd(fdData[obsItems])
  plot(fdClsMean[j])
  j <- j + 1
}
```

The variable $fdClsMean$ should now contain the the mean-Curves for classes 2 (j=1) and 3 (j=2).

But by doing this way, I get the following error message:

> Error in basisobj$type : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In fdClsMean[j] <- mean.fd(fdData[obsItems]) :
>      number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
>   2: In fdClsMean[j] <- mean.fd(fdData[obsItems]) :
>      number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

If you have some idea to fix my problem, it would deeply grateful to share this to fix my issues...

```
library("fda", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
library("Funclustering", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
library("RColorBrewer")


dataParam1 <- structure(c(0.983981396374184, 0.985667565176901, 0.987353733979619, 
                             0.989039902782336, 0.990726071585054, 0.992412240387771, 0.994098409190489, 
                             0.995784577993206, 0.997470746795924, 0.999156915598641, 1.00084308440136, 
                             1.00252925320408, 1.00421542200679, 1.00590159080951, 1.00758775961223, 
                             1.00927392841495, 1.01096009721766, 1.01264626602038, 1.0143324348231, 
                             1.01601860362582), .Dim = c(20L, 1L))
dataParam2 <- structure(c(0.935807922166589, 0.943068751205336, 0.950253873594361, 
                            0.957301033607757, 0.964196288650217, 0.970959127061196, 0.977617918964004, 
                            0.984189979476357, 0.990668963023258, 0.997013182869952, 1.00323559960119, 
                            1.00938298993635, 1.01547786768659, 1.02152013701955, 1.0274999384715, 
                            1.0334274313317, 1.03932634191985, 1.04522750712415, 1.05115275864212, 
                            1.05710855288827, 0.944940959736965, 0.952240113360859, 0.959441049641086, 
                            0.966488172817292, 0.97341343344192, 0.980222400271887, 0.986902496653507, 
                            0.993448451457477, 0.99986985906694, 1.00619310390116, 1.01243170737101, 
                            1.01858974507763, 1.02466601555031, 1.03064904117653, 1.03651652181871, 
                            1.04225550204583, 1.04786681255322, 1.05337761542761, 1.05881863137361, 
                            1.06421715026136, 0.942134107403247, 0.949453882063492, 0.956590162743654, 
                            0.96357651793391, 0.970434299161641, 0.977175121667198, 0.983804637900584, 
                            0.990326873791272, 0.996747607095444, 1.00308113105998, 1.00933426721898, 
                            1.01549301552775, 1.02154277232314, 1.02747204422399, 1.0332709082207, 
                            1.03893203367462, 1.04446158372569, 1.04987525096791, 1.05520008265379, 
                            1.06046511659515, 0.940314383500459, 0.947443682667925, 0.954466467035383, 
                            0.961381593377821, 0.968188153734298, 0.974880350284026, 0.981455066595135, 
                            0.987919638428396, 0.994283132996982, 1.00055457342423, 1.00673992698461, 
                            1.01284173849434, 1.01885881474915, 1.02478559454537, 1.03060319500227, 
                            1.03629277173835, 1.04185574786414, 1.04730757048597, 1.05268469714051, 
                            1.05802280631965, 0.942200273210682, 0.949537004317527, 0.956623599167406, 
                            0.963557498320244, 0.970424531942181, 0.977192573805136, 0.983814211488919, 
                            0.990277133991018, 0.996653057498476, 1.00300075654431, 1.00933625505411, 
                            1.01557529576456, 1.02166231349206, 1.02762357846321, 1.03350687583051, 
                            1.0393552762534, 1.04517784054144, 1.05097645707751, 1.05675187074763, 
                            1.06250633686837, 0.918631352137535, 0.926168759248379, 0.933383610717465, 
                            0.940494686251366, 0.947502148141247, 0.954389475599439, 0.961178237128648, 
                            0.967896560645279, 0.974461153761216, 0.980830749331793, 0.987116074571801, 
                            0.99342184407008, 0.99972724615763, 1.00590479212328, 1.01188232533948, 
                            1.01767723457145, 1.02335415372681, 1.02896316014817, 1.03452862636983, 
                            1.0400636313845, 0.948799842055992, 0.95604267242623, 0.963156714842769, 
                            0.970143065897736, 0.97700934008937, 0.983765186828579, 0.990417394142179, 
                            0.996974994464174, 1.00344983548711, 1.00984462195143, 1.01615468562631, 
                            1.02236814859822, 1.02847302994779, 1.0344602037918, 1.04032333101854, 
                            1.04606311135653, 1.0517058460477, 1.05728582670374, 1.06283690174272, 
                            1.06837903584947, 0.937423306587466, 0.944893372711674, 0.952215313085228, 
                            0.959400162368507, 0.966459044310274, 0.973365235191435, 0.980115166296175, 
                            0.986739018932661, 0.993253673429198, 0.999669550405327, 1.0059957825912, 
                            1.012243755661, 1.01842325413489, 1.02453580456187, 1.03057996323426, 
                            1.03655461352516, 1.04246624447002, 1.04832385360279, 1.05413680517058, 
                            1.05991330934091, 0.929064626164736, 0.936318053087355, 0.943487918232746, 
                            0.950544729360738, 0.957477543275641, 0.964285599365032, 0.970974339717291, 
                            0.977549594039067, 0.984023864258173, 0.990424135490678, 0.996768075950284, 
                            1.00305982852269, 1.00929091001667, 1.01544534554472, 1.02150212798765, 
                            1.02744072592741, 1.03324516748151, 1.03892952896684, 1.04453104163349, 
                            1.05008784822354, 0.93174505802589, 0.93913180070802, 0.946369086629952, 
                            0.953430967475995, 0.960342639111208, 0.967156853413704, 0.973912193750937, 
                            0.980515241879027, 0.986922063141707, 0.993226171372671, 0.999502978127663, 
                            1.00578905610495, 1.01204829399176, 1.01823525590035, 1.02431611212046, 
                            1.03025344575662, 1.03602479561377, 1.04166823872877, 1.04723886048702, 
                            1.05279403456375), .Dim = c(20L, 10L))
dataParam3 <- structure(c(1.09752068287775, 1.06097903366602, 1.02849490570095, 
                            1.00006829898254, 0.975699213510778, 0.955387649285669, 0.939133606307212, 
                            0.926937084575411, 0.918798084090263, 0.91471660485177, 0.914692646859928, 
                            0.918726210114739, 0.926817294616202, 0.938965900364315, 0.955172027359076, 
                            0.975435675600487, 0.999756845088542, 1.02813553582325, 1.06057174780459, 
                            1.09706548103259, 1.15326107555771, 1.09807034962895, 1.05134196032301, 
                            1.0130026453226, 0.98288375314881, 0.960918342480959, 0.947105518522033, 
                            0.941413952185788, 0.942411639052145, 0.946950432124294, 0.95383973098054, 
                            0.963066506646878, 0.974630759123311, 0.98853248840984, 1.00477169450647, 
                            1.02334837741319, 1.04426253713001, 1.06751417365691, 1.09310328699392, 
                            1.12102987714102, 1.08280188279282, 1.0339980008814, 0.99569456675958, 
                            0.96693069628092, 0.945845840346565, 0.930481541243696, 0.919050991554413, 
                            0.911059810335648, 0.906507018011789, 0.905392614582835, 0.907716600048786, 
                            0.913478974409641, 0.9226797376654, 0.935318889816062, 0.951396430861627, 
                            0.970912360802095, 0.993866679637463, 1.02025938736774, 1.05009048399292, 
                            1.083359969513, 1.07095942421253, 1.03585502956334, 1.00549026148582, 
                            0.979865119979976, 0.958979605045805, 0.942833716683301, 0.931427454892467, 
                            0.924759134770715, 0.922715496413862, 0.925000988457256, 0.931232021681892, 
                            0.940974907301548, 0.954057033380912, 0.970475602146626, 0.99023061359869, 
                            1.0133220677371, 1.03974996456186, 1.06951430407298, 1.10261508627044, 
                            1.13905231115425, 1.11173319871675, 1.07474700125511, 1.04289364687089, 
                            1.015144362519, 0.991499148199451, 0.971958003912224, 0.956520929657326, 
                            0.94518792543476, 0.937950419475085, 0.934666308796689, 0.935126761169374, 
                            0.939286949471352, 0.947146873129281, 0.95870653214316, 0.97396592651299, 
                            0.992925056238774, 1.01558392132051, 1.0419425217582, 1.07200085755185, 
                            1.10575892870146, 1.18452158624921, 1.12370399561361, 1.07335363604345, 
                            1.03347050753872, 1.00405461009944, 0.985101985787768, 0.975484170734052, 
                            0.971553828495674, 0.970543650731045, 0.971115755631005, 0.973165208428402, 
                            0.97669200912324, 0.981696157715515, 0.988177654205224, 0.996136498592366, 
                            1.00557269087694, 1.01648623105895, 1.02887711913838, 1.04274535511525, 
                            1.05809093898954, 1.06649113627055, 1.024759151488, 0.991993644427598, 
                            0.966493902211868, 0.946597045425109, 0.931024085529654, 0.919567682099019, 
                            0.912227835133204, 0.90900454463221, 0.909897810596039, 0.914907633024689, 
                            0.92403008262567, 0.936993197222042, 0.953120075509914, 0.972106114234723, 
                            0.993944684266615, 1.01863578560559, 1.04617941825165, 1.07657558220479, 
                            1.10982427746502, 1.1253871751946, 1.08517168478315, 1.05718721613491, 
                            1.03386322378679, 1.01386163522085, 0.996961380709181, 0.983162460251796, 
                            0.972464873848689, 0.96486862149986, 0.960373703205309, 0.958980118965034, 
                            0.960687868779034, 0.965496952647307, 0.973407370569853, 0.984419122546672, 
                            0.998532208577764, 1.01574662866313, 1.03606238280277, 1.05947947099668, 
                            1.08599789324487, 1.10370505705101, 1.07105955490089, 1.042537295611, 
                            1.01813827918133, 0.997862505611908, 0.981709974902708, 0.969649294946133, 
                            0.961487003409706, 0.957046106397668, 0.956305216070678, 0.959264332428738, 
                            0.965923455471853, 0.976282585200022, 0.990341721613246, 1.00810086471153, 
                            1.02956001449487, 1.05471917096326, 1.08357833411671, 1.11613750395523, 
                            1.15239574124661, 1.17014704608091, 1.12539391342114, 1.08622797779053, 
                            1.05264923918907, 1.02465769761678, 1.00225335307363, 0.985253167489029, 
                            0.972675875945994, 0.963752595681981, 0.958418763926775, 0.956674380680374, 
                            0.95851944594278, 0.963953959713992, 0.972977921994012, 0.985591332782836, 
                            1.00179419208046, 1.02158649988689, 1.04496825620213, 1.07193946102617, 
                            1.10250011435902), .Dim = c(20L, 10L))
dataParam4 <- structure(c(0.998027622801379, 0.998139005663452, 0.998271051914594, 
                           0.998423328203811, 0.998595824570253, 0.998787296486765, 0.998993932660538, 
                           0.999210129159112, 0.999431146138834, 0.999656257754324, 0.999883808694126, 
                           1.00011168941983, 1.00033957014554, 1.00056745087124, 1.00079533159695, 
                           1.00102321232266, 1.00125109304836, 1.00147897377407, 1.00170685449977, 
                           1.00193473522548, 0.998889268641521, 0.998995305981988, 0.999133764074945, 
                           0.99928651296306, 0.999452207584217, 0.999630847938417, 0.99982243402566, 
                           1.00002692932507, 1.00024266452332, 1.00046582375815, 1.00069345965806, 
                           1.00092367291089, 1.00115613664618, 1.00139085086393, 1.00162781556414, 
                           1.0018670307468, 1.00210849641193, 1.0023521950849, 1.00259752350583, 
                           1.0028432697472, 0.99858396998391, 0.99870387003, 0.998847936377362, 
                           0.999013112737924, 0.999193672030613, 0.999385662628316, 0.999586590108664, 
                           0.999795769265012, 1.00001319873968, 1.00023887520213, 1.00047211431565, 
                           1.00071073589431, 1.00095287258822, 1.00119740014348, 1.00144380788341, 
                           1.00169207895861, 1.00194221336906, 1.00219421111478, 1.00244807219575, 
                           1.00270379661199, 0.998270181390647, 0.998401339075749, 0.998551858486823, 
                           0.998714133501672, 0.998888127245082, 0.999073839717051, 0.999271270917581, 
                           0.999480396599729, 0.999699586873158, 0.999924714214518, 1.00015335625382, 
                           1.00038507691478, 1.00061973867722, 1.00085733931215, 1.00109787881957, 
                           1.00134135719949, 1.00158777258983, 1.00183667764293, 1.00208661796178, 
                           1.00233662699637, 0.998524744128797, 0.99863486766656, 0.998766395000859, 
                           0.998919231110539, 0.999090190884781, 0.99927303979413, 0.999465840024052, 
                           0.999667849206214, 0.99987677069341, 1.00009092850323, 1.00030946243406, 
                           1.00053217357039, 1.00075802790152, 1.00098471847949, 1.00121141596579, 
                           1.00143811345209, 1.0016648109384, 1.0018915084247, 1.002118205911, 
                           1.00234490339731, 0.997142773287418, 0.997216060623538, 0.997337368533094, 
                           0.99748694099883, 0.997653350796102, 0.997832448382706, 0.998024129720826, 
                           0.998228394810461, 0.998445199575133, 0.9986718900988, 0.998902679532502, 
                           0.999136069032265, 0.999372057841899, 0.999610645961405, 0.999851833390782, 
                           1.00009562013003, 1.00034200617915, 1.00059099153814, 1.00084257620701, 
                           1.00109676018574, 0.998774949267013, 0.998910297833251, 0.999061521216158, 
                           0.999227984680012, 0.999409687603104, 0.999605338922452, 0.99980970198149, 
                           1.00001925408346, 1.00023376857386, 1.00045324545269, 1.00067768471994, 
                           1.00090707945052, 1.00114095033083, 1.00137806194375, 1.00161725633342, 
                           1.00185762361078, 1.00209895072581, 1.00234123762244, 1.00258448430066, 
                           1.00282869076048, 0.998235072519545, 0.998344557202282, 0.998473860627503, 
                           0.998622982795209, 0.9987919237054, 0.998980556065077, 0.999185038787191, 
                           0.999398230779131, 0.999618154290144, 0.999844806347269, 1.00007793486253, 
                           1.00031476590786, 1.00055208167417, 1.00078941271967, 1.00102675904437, 
                           1.00126412064827, 1.00150149743951, 1.00173888541517, 1.00197627612265, 
                           1.00221366684226, 0.997626171909553, 0.997748769141173, 0.997905556676881, 
                           0.998072158983953, 0.998246774313143, 0.998429402664452, 0.998620044037878, 
                           0.998818696371925, 0.999024892332026, 0.999237142122056, 0.999454583203959, 
                           0.999677175584942, 0.999904919265005, 1.00013781424415, 1.00037584615344, 
                           1.00061802820279, 1.00086189544351, 1.00110629255917, 1.00135119016537, 
                           1.00159658826211, 0.99786182119536, 0.997943059648897, 0.998068582740041, 
                           0.998214894107906, 0.998377432849961, 0.998555103351116, 0.998747881433229, 
                           0.998955724328998, 0.999175663350038, 0.999400370426972, 0.999626749674934, 
                           0.999854748906657, 1.00008436812214, 1.00031560732139, 1.0005484665044, 
                           1.00078294567116, 1.00101904482169, 1.00125676395599, 1.00149610307404, 
                           1.00173700388097), .Dim = c(20L, 10L))



# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#   Param1
# ####################################################################################
xVal <- as.vector(dataParam1)
nObs <- dim(dataParam3)[2]



# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#   Param2
# ####################################################################################
# Build the basis expansion system for Param2
fdBasisParam2 <- create.bspline.basis(rangeval = range(xVal), norder=6)

# Calculate the coefficients for Param2 as matrix at once
yVal <- as.matrix(dataParam2)
fdParam2 <- Data2fd(argvals=xVal,y=yVal, basisobj=fdBasisParam2, lambda=0)
round(fdParam2$coefs, 4)
rm(yVal)
plot(fdParam2)


# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#   Param3
# ####################################################################################
# Build the basis expansion system for Param3
fdBasisParam3 <- create.bspline.basis(rangeval = range(xVal), norder=3)

# Calculate the coefficients for Param3 as matrix at once
yVal <- as.matrix(dataParam3)
fdParam3 <- Data2fd(argvals=xVal,y=yVal, basisobj=fdBasisParam3, lambda=0)
round(fdParam3$coefs, 4)
rm(yVal)
plot(fdParam3)


# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#   Param4
# ####################################################################################
# Build the basis expansion system for Param4
fdBasisParam4 <- create.bspline.basis(rangeval = range(xVal), norder=3)

# Calculate the coefficients for Param4 as matrix at once
yVal <- as.matrix(dataParam4)
fdParam4 <- Data2fd(argvals=xVal,y=yVal, basisobj=fdBasisParam4, lambda=0)
round(fdParam4$coefs, 4)
rm(yVal)
plot(fdParam4)


# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
#   Clustering multivariate functional Data with funclust algorithm
# ####################################################################################
# -- Create a multivariate functional data object
allFd <- list(fdParam2,fdParam3,fdParam4)

# -- clustering in K classes
K <- 3      # Number of clusters
thd <- 0.05  # Threshold for Cantell Scree-Test
hard <- FALSE
nLoop <- 1

cls <- c()
tik <- c()
for (i in 1:nLoop) {
  clustResult <- funclust(allFd,
                          K=K,
                          thd=thd,
                          increaseDimension=FALSE,
                          hard=hard
  )
  tik <- rbind(round((clustResult$tik)*100, 2))
  cls <- rbind(cls,clustResult$cls)
}



#
# Calculation of class-specific characteristics
#
uniGroups <- sort(unique(as.vector(cls)))

fbParam2ClsMean <- list()
fbParam3ClsMean <- list()
fbParam4ClsMean <- list()
j <- 1

for (i in uniGroups) {
  obsItems <- which(cls %in% i)

  # Mean values
  fbParam2ClsMean[[j]] <- mean.fd(fdParam2[obsItems])
  fbParam3ClsMean[[j]] <- mean.fd(fdParam3[obsItems])
  fbParam4ClsMean[[j]] <- mean.fd(fdParam4[obsItems])
  j <- j+1
}
plot(fbParam2ClsMean)
plot(fbParam3ClsMean)
plot(fbParam4ClsMean)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional errors are caused by the output of `mean.fd(fdData[obsItems])`, not a single element. you need `list()` to put it. (`listname[[1]]` means 1st object in the list.)

```
fdClsMean <- list()

for (i in uniGroups) {
  obsItems <- which(cls %in% i)  # what is cls ??
  fdClsMean[[j]] <- mean.fd(fdData[obsItems])
  plot(fdClsMean[[j]])
  j <- j + 1
}
```

#### [Edited]

Your `fbParamXClsMean` is a class `list` and have three `fd` objects. you need to pick up one `fd` object when you draw it.

for example;

```
plot(fbParam2ClsMean[[1]])
plot(fbParam2ClsMean[[2]], add=T, col=2, lty=2)
plot(fbParam2ClsMean[[3]], add=T, col=3, lty=3)

# if use for()
a <- FALSE
for(i in 1:3) {
  plot(fbParam2ClsMean[[i]], col = i, lty = i, add = a)
  a <- TRUE
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. At the first look it seems to work. But if you try to plot the data you get an error message. That is why I provide the requested reproducible example - attached to my initial question. I hope my question is a little bit clearer, now. :)

Comment: I saw the question at asked in your snippet a few minutes ago. The variable 'cls' is the same as 'clsResult' at my short example above. In the long and reproducible example it is called 'cls'.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help. Sure your solution works definitely but I would like to use the capabilities of the fda-package - it provides several calculation and plotting methods for handling of these objects.

Therefore I'd like to propose my solution:

1. Create an fd-object based on an existing b-spline expansion system (e.g. called `fdParam2Mean`). While the matrix `fdParam2ClsMean$coefs` is filled with zeros, I delete these manually.

   ```
   fdParam2ClsMean <- fd(coef=NULL, basisobj=fdParam2$basis)
   fdParam2ClsMean$coefs <- fdParam2ClsMean$coefs[,-1]
   ```
2. Request the class names and store them in `uniGroups`

   ```
   uniGroups <- sort(unique(as.vector(cls)))
   ```
3. Iterate through the `uniGroups` for calculation of statistics (like mean, standard deviation etc.)

   ```
   for (i in uniGroups) {
     obsItems <- which(cls %in% i)

     # Mean values
     fdParam2ClsMean$coefs <- cbind(fdParam2ClsMean$coefs, as.array(mean.fd(fdParam2[obsItems])$coefs))
   }
   ```
4. After these operations you are able to process this objects with mathematical operations or for example use the `plot()` command.

   ```
   plot(fdParam2ClsMean)
   ```